# Using Zend Validate Float with a specific locale

Tags: zend-framework, validation, zend-form

```
 $text = new Zend_Form_Element_Text();
            $ValidateRange =  new Zend_Validate_Between(0, 999999.99);
            $ValidateFloat = new Zend_Validate_Float();
            $ValidateFloat->setLocale(new Zend_Locale('de_AT'));
            $ValidateRange->setMessage('Please enter the amount between [0-9999] ');
            $textValidateFloat->setMessage('Please enter the amount properly');                  
            $text->addValidator($ValidateRange);
            $text->addValidator($ValidateFloat);
```

The above code works fine if we enter value like 12,23 . If we enter 12.23 the form didn't show any error message . How we can show error message . Please help me . thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the Zend/Validate/Float code, it always checks both your defined locale *and* english:

```
if (!Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat($value, array('locale' => 'en')) &&
    !Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat($value, array('locale' => $this->_locale))) {
```

So, you'll need to extend or rewrite this validator yourself, removing the 'locale'=>'en' part.

edit:

Your validator, extending Zend_Validate_Float, can look something like this:

```
public function isValid( $value )
{
    if ( !parent::isValid($value) ) return false;

    if (!Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat($value, array('locale' => 'de_AT'))) {
        $this->_error(self::NOT_FLOAT);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```